# Change drawable xml color from widget

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to change the color of the drawable xml from the **widget**. Things that need to be considered is the drawable xml has a round radius, and the drawable needs to be set to a relative/ linear layout so that it wraps up the content.

I have tried setting the drawable to and imageview and setting the color through `setColorFilter`. This wont work for me as I need it wrapped to a layout

Changing color of relative layout with `setBackgroundColor` will replace the drawable leaving no corner radius.

Color is changed dynamically so cant set it in drawable or use multiple drawable

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_36sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_36sdp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_custom_color"
    android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your java class

```
((GradientDrawable) imgBackground.getBackground()).setColor(listColors.get(position));
```

here "listColors" is

```
ArrayList<Integer> listColors=getColorList();

public ArrayList<Integer> getColorList() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    int[] bg_colors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.bg_color);
   
     for (int i = 0; i < bg_colors.length; i++) {
         list.add(bg_colors[i]);
     }

 return list;
}
```